# Use conditional logic for woocommerce variable product

Tags: plugins, variables

I have been developing a woocommerce store. Now I have a requirement from client which I can't figure out how to do...

The problem is we can use variable product in woocommerce, it's simple but what I need is to use conditional logic for variable products. Let's be more specific.

Our product is a Ear Ring. Which may have 2, 3 or 4 bags . Like the image :
![The Product sample][1]. So when adding the product to cart, user have to choose 1) Number of Bags (1,2,3 or 4) 2),

If he select 1 pouches then another dropdown will be shown to choose color & style of the bag, if he select 2 bags then 2 dropdowns will be shown, if he select 3 bags, then 3 dropdowns will be shown.

Please see the product image here to understand my requirement clearly :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WD6F.jpg

Basically I need this kind of conditional logic in woocommerce.

Thanks

Comment: This is a **WooCommerce** question, *not* a **WordPress** question. From the [FAQ]: "*Note that we do not handle questions...not specific to WordPress (**even if they happen in its context**)*"

Comment: Woocommerce offers a plugin called [gravity forms add on](http://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/) which uses gravity forms to add forms to your product page(note: if you don't already have gravity forms, you will need to purchase it for this to work). Gravity forms allows you to set conditional logic for the (options)dropdowns you create. I.E. show "this" option if "this" option is selected. This extension also makes it easier if there are price addons so you don't have to set up all of the prices for each and every possible combination

Comment: The question is having high traffic, so i thought I can add a solution here:
Recently there are quite a few woocommerce addon plugins are available on the market which allows do use conditional logic. Here's one of those which works really good. [Woocommerce Extra Product Options.](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619?ref=ThemeNcode)

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but here you go:

```
<?php

if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){

  // a simple product

} elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ){

  // a variable product

}
// If you need a Product object for the above:
$product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
```

Found it here: https://gist.github.com/patrickgilmour/9d4a28b4a2f0c1dcecbf and here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/condition-to-check-if-product-is-simple-or-variable.

I'm glad this question wasn't closed :)